Capital income growth equals labor income growth along the balanced growth path
I am trying to show that when technological and population growths are (non-negative) constants, the rate of growth of capital income and labor income in the steady state will be equal. Assume that the production function is given by $F(K(t), A(t)L(t))$, and that the growth rates of population and technological progress are $n$ and $g$ respectively. All other variables used are standard and as used by authors like Acemoglu.

Define $W = wL$ and $R = rK$ For brevity, we will avoid writing the $t$-argument of every function, that is, we will write the variable $L(t)$ as $L$.
Claim: $g_W = \frac{\dot{W}}{W} = \frac{\dot{R}}{R} = g_R$ along the balanced growth path (or in the steady state).
Proof. The claim $g_W = g_R$ is equivalent to $\frac{\dot w}{w} + \frac{\dot L}{L} = \frac{\dot r}{r} + \frac{\dot K}{K} \iff \frac{\dot w}{w} + n = \frac{\dot r}{r} + g+n \iff \frac{\dot w}{w} = \frac{\dot{r}}{r} + g$. Note that we obtained $\frac{\dot{K}}{K} = g+n$ from $\frac{d}{dt}\left[\ln\left(\frac{K}{AL}\right)\right] = \frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(k^{*}\right)\right] = 0$ where $k^{*}$ is the steady state value of $k$.
Now we get, after some tedious calculations, that

$\displaystyle \frac{\dot w}{w} = \frac{\dot{A} [f(\tilde k) - \tilde k f'(\tilde k)]}{A [f(\tilde k) - \tilde k f'(\tilde k)]} = \frac{\dot A}{A} = g$ where $\tilde k:= \frac{K}{AL}$ and $w$ is given by $\frac{\partial F(K,AL)}{\partial L}$.
$\displaystyle \frac{\dot r}{r} = \frac{f''(\tilde k) \dot{\tilde{k}}}{f'(\tilde k)} = 0$ where $\tilde k$ is defined as above.

Combining the two results, it is immediate that $g_W = g_R$.

Question to the forum: My instructor considered labor income $(W)$ as $wAL$ as opposed to $wL$. Further, he deduced, without showing the deductions, that $\frac{\dot w}{w} = 0$ where $w$ is the wage rate. Eventually, the two growth rates came out to be equal. However, his growth rate of $w$ is completely different from mine and so are the definitions. I wonder who did it correctly, me or my instructor.

Dear, I suggest you the Michio Morishima paper Economic expansion and the interest rate in generalized v. Neumann model

Your results are not  at variance with the result of your teacher, there  are just  different definitions of wage, your $w$ is not the same as the $w$ of your teacher.
The labor income your teacher considers is of $\tilde {w}AL$, instead of $wL$ as in your case, where $\tilde {w}$ is the wage for unit of effective labor $AL$, not per worker $L$ as $w$.
In his model the wage per worker is $w= \frac {\tilde {w}AL}{L}= \tilde {w}A$.
As a consequence, if the rate of growth of  $\tilde {w}$ is zero,  the rate of growth of $w$ is equal to the rate of growth of $A$, $g$, as in your model: in both cases the result is that the per worker wage grows at the same rate of productivity.
Why is the rate of growth of  $\tilde {w}$ zero?
I suppose that your professor  equates the wage $\tilde {w}$ to the marginal productivity of effective labor $AL$, and the latter depends only on $\tilde {k}= K/{AL}$, and $\tilde {k}$ in steady state is constant:  that is $\dot {\tilde {w}}=0$.
Indeed, recalling that that the production function is homogeneous of degree one,   we can write it as $$Y= AL f(K/AL)= AL f(\tilde {k}).$$
Differentiating with respect to $AL$ we have:
$$\tilde {w}= \frac{\partial (Y)}{\partial (AL)}= AL f’\left(\frac {K}{AL}\right) \left(-\frac {K}{(AL)^2}\right)+f\left(\frac {K}{AL}\right)=f(\tilde {k})-\tilde{k} f’(\tilde {k}).$$
This last  expression  depends uniquely on $\tilde {k}$, which in steady state is constant, and therefore $\tilde {w}$ is constant.

I don't doubt that my instructor or I myself did the calculations incorrectly. I'm only trying to figure out which set of definitions is more standard, his or mine.
